# How to use threads in Qt GUI

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have an application that continuously reads an image from a camera and displays this to a user. The user can adjust different sliders such as exposure and threshold to modify the image in real-time. I also do a bunch of calculations on this image afterwards which sometimes makes the GUI unresponsive, so I decided to use threads to divide the workload.

However, I can't get it to work properly, sometimes I get segmentation faults and a bunch of "assertion ` GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed" warnings when the slider values are changed or if I try to save the image (save button in my GUI), and the GUI sometimes stops updating the image or freezes so you can't move the sliders or push any buttons.

What I tried to do was to use the standard std::thread in C++, and connect it to the start button through a slot.

```
QObject::connect(btnStart, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(RunStartThread()));

void MainMenu::RunStartThread(){
std::thread t1;
t1= std::thread(&MainMenu::Start,this);
t1.detach();
}

void MainMenu::Start() {
run = true;    
    window->mngr->ReadCalibration();
    window->mngr->InitializeCameras();

    while (run) {

        window->mngr->CaptureImage();
        window->mngr->ProcessImages();            
        UpdateLabels();
      }  

window->mngr->Stop();
}
```

When the user changes the slider values they change variables in my manager (mngr above) that captureImage and ProcessImages uses. I tried using a std::mutex lock/unlock when a variable was to be accessed, but it did not change anything. I've tried to find examples of how to do this online, but have yet to find something that has a continuous while-loop.

I'm a newbie when it comes to threads, so just tell me if I'm approaching this in the wrong way.

Comment: Maybe you'd better use [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html)?

Comment: Hopefully, the functions of your mngr instance do not access any QT widgets directly. If you want to achieve any changes in the GUI from within the second thread (UpdateLabels()?), you have to do this via signal/slot, too!

Comment: The updates from the sliders are managed through signal/slot, and the manager does not have access to the Qt widgets at all. The GUI has a connection to the manager but not the other way around. UpdateLabels simply gets some image info from the manager and updates labels in the GUI. Sorry for not clarifying. 
I have tried looking into Qthread, but I have not found any good examples on how to do it.

Comment: "UpdateLabels simply gets some image info from the manager and updates labels in the GUI" - via signal/slot?

Comment: No, not through signal/slot. Just, when the image has been processed, I call UpdateLabels to change label texts. UpdateLabels has nothing to do with the sliders and it is not causing any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First for all for inter thread communication use singnals and slots. By default Qt connections do nice thread hopping between threads which lets to avoid complex synchronization.

Secondly you have three ways of using threads: [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html), [QRunnable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrunnable.html), [QtConcurrent::Run](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrent.html#run) (my favorite, since requires minimum amount of code).

In case `QThread` please do not subclass it! It is [common design mistake](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/).

Example:

```
SomeClass::~SomeClass()
{
    SignalStop();
    future.result();
}

void SomeClass::RunStartThread(){
     future = QtConcurrent::run(this, &SomeClass::DoOnThread);
}

void SomeClass::DoOnThread()
{
    while (ShouldContinueToRun()) {
        QImage im1 = CaptureImage();
        emit ImageCaptured(im1);
        QImage im2 = ProcessImages(im1);            
        emit ImageProcessed(im2);
    }
    emit JobCompleted();
}
```

Please note that [QObject::connect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect) has last argument which defines how invocation of slot is performed if different thread is involved. See [documentation of enumeration](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum) used for this argument.
So by default Qt detects if thread hopping is needed or not. Reading carefully about [QObject::moveToThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) should also help to understand the problem (note you can't move object to different thread if it has a parent).

Comment: Following your link, then in your example, wouldn't have `SomeClass` have to inherit from `QThreadPool`? Would rather expect `doOnThread` to be static and have a parameter `SomeClass*` and to call `run(&doOnThread, this);`. What did I miss?

Comment: If the images are shown using opencv's imshow, do I  reallly need to emit a signal that the image has been captured? Processed sure, since updatelabels depends on this. But how would I connect that signal to the updateLabels() function/slot? Same with the JobCompleted, how do I connect this signal to my functions?

Comment: @Aconcagua See [this part of the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtconcurrentrun.html#using-member-functions).

Comment: my example is with third option `QtConcurrent::Run` so you do not need to inherit anything (like I wrote code simplicity). In second option you have to inherit `QRunnable`. `QThreadPool` is the tool which runs `QRunnable` and should not be extended!

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted if you can answer my comment. How do I connect the signals if I decide to emit a signal within the thread as in your example?

Comment: in regular way. By default Qt makes a connection which during emit of signal checks if destination objects belongs to different thread, if it does then it posts invocation of slot to respective event loop, if it doesn't belong to different thread it just invokes slot. See [documentation of enumeration used as last argument of connect](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum).

Comment: I'm still not sure how to do it, the connect function looks like this: QObject::connect(const QObject * sender, const char * signal, const QObject * receiver, const char * method). Normally you have a for e.g. a pushbutton as sender and use "this" as receiver. What would I use for those arguments if I implement the threadstuff like in your example using QtConcurrent?

Comment: Just do it as you did it before. Default behavior will do the job you need.

Comment: The only problem you can encounter is that custom types passed by such connection have to have meta data know to Qt. If you will use `QImage` or `QPixmap` everything will work without problems or extra code. Just try do it It will work out of the box.

Comment: Well with the exception that `QPixmap` might throw a warning, that you are not using it in the main thread. So just stick with `QImage` :)